# Is my game at risk of fines due to CVAA if I don't support text-to-speech in chat?

Tags: text, online, voice, accessibility

Looking at a similar game like Among Us: as far as I know, it only has in text chat as a norm of communication. Shouldn't the game be obligated to have more options for disabilities like text to speech to meet the requirements of the US laws of CVAA?

I want to develop a game with voice and text channels, and I am concerned this may expose me to risk, because adding special things for disabilities will simply not work and it would be so costly by me.

https://www.reddit.com/r/GamerGhazi/comments/ac774q/starting_this_year_games_will_need_to_implement/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GROVGdetG4

https://www.thenerdmag.com/video-games-in-us-will-now-require-text-to-speech-and-vice-versa-to-cater-disabilities/

Neither PUBG, CSGO, VALORANT, DESTINY has text-to-speech options. Are companies ignoring the rule, or for as long as you are a big corporation with good lawyers this doesn't apply to you?

I as an indie developer with my idea won't stand a chance. What should I do?

Comment: Yes Among Us lacks accessibility options. Are they breaking the law? I don't know. I can read the referenced article, however I'm having a hard time finding that on the actual legal text. Furthermore, I don't know if it is ok for games to rely on screen readers, nor if Among Us supports them. About, gameaccessibilityguidelines.com, those are guidelines, not the law, nobody is requiring to implement the full list. And, no, bicycles are not covered by the CVAA. The CVAA is about communication (and thus it makes sense that it regulates over text chat).

Comment: So all it takes is for a blind american to sue the game and poof?

Comment: For what I understand there are no lawsuits over CVAA, only complains. So, a blind person issues a complain, the FCC verifies the claim, then they contact the developer, they have a grace period to solve the issue (or, if I'm reading correctly, show they can't do it - which could the be way out for indie developers). If the developer does not cooperate on the process, then the FCC will charge a fine.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and this is exactly what I wanted to confirm, I had the same understanding from that conference... and seems like actually a good rule if it's actually the case. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why your game idea won't stand a chance. Is it because text to speech? I can find some cloud based text to speech APIs that could be integrated into mobile games with a free tier. Of course, the free tier will have limitation. Well, solve monetization. Perhaps your game idea should be a paid game. If that is not your issue, I'd suggest to ask about your problem at hand.

Comment: Look at this game. There are hundreds of text at the same time. How in the world would you implement ttp to that? How would you make this game accessible to bout with the rules? https://youtu.be/ETNVoepkYeY

Comment: No, I won't put MMO chat to text to speech. On that I agree. I wish I could find something  about CVAA and direct communications… If it comes to it, I'd say provide an option to run text to speech on direct messages only.

Comment: I agree. This would be the best thing to do. Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me like this question is answered in the very first link you cite: "Third-party solutions, as long as they are available to the consumer 'at nominal cost' are also accepted. If it isn't feasible to implement them (e.g. indie dev too small, too little funds), then they can be let off." — what do you need us to explain that's not already covered in the research you've done?

Comment: If you'd like help finding efficient ways to make your game more accessible, try editing your question to *tell us about your game*. We wouldn't give the same advice to Among Us as we would to Destiny, so sharing details of your game can help us find appropriate solutions for your particular needs.